# Overloading [,] operator in F#

Tags: f#

How can I overload the operator [,] (as in 2D Arrays) in F#? I would like to be able to write something like: `myObject.[a, b]`.

Answer (score 8):

That's an "indexed property". There's an example of an indexed property with multiple arguments at the bottom of the [Indexed Properties (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx) page on MSDN.